# Probability associated with the kth order statistics

Tags: probability, beta-distribution, order-statistics

The distribution function of the $k^{th}$ order statistics is 
$$F(X_{(k:n)} = I_{F(x)}(k,n-k+1)$$
But, I am interested to know the probability associated with $k^{th}$ order statistics.In a recent article in Ocean Engineering journal, [Muraleedharan2016](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0029801816300634?via%3Dihub) the author mentioned that the probability associated with the $k^{th}$ orderstatistic $x_{(k)}$ is given by $ p_k = I_{0.5}^{-1}(k, n-k+1)$, where $I_{0.5}^{-1}(k, n-k+1)$ is the inverse regularized beta function. [image: Ref to image for further details]. I am seriously confused how to obtain this probability and what's the logic that the author mentioned the probability to be
$I_{0.5}^{-1}(k, n-k+1)$. Is the case true only when the ordered statistics are taken from the uniform distribution? But why is it true when the order statistics in the article are not from uniform distribution?